# Pass a DropDownId to asp button control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to navigate from one Asp Web page to another Asp Web page by using an id of a drop-down. How can i pass a simple DropdownID to an asp button control ?

Comment: try to store id  in hiddenfield on dropdown change event using jquery or c#   and than get that id on button click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the dropdown to do a `Response.Redirect` to the next page while concatenating your DropdownId in the redirect url as a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your dropdown something like this

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  id="ddl"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionChanged"
                  AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Page 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Page 2" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And selectedindex method as below

```
protected void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx?QueryString="+((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
}
```

As you can see you don't need extra button to redirect to specific page